# Installing .pkg with terminal ?

Tags: terminal, install, pkg

Is it possible to install a .pkg using a terminal ? (I wanted to install an app through ssh).

Answer (score 192, accepted):

#### /usr/sbin/installer

> The installer command is used to install Mac OS X installer packages to a specified domain or volume.  The
> installer command installs a single package per invocation, which is specified with the -package parameter ( -pkg
> is accepted as a synonym).  It may be either a single package or a metapackage.  In the case of the metapackage,
> the packages which are part of the default install will be installed unless disqualified by a package's check
> tool(s).

See `man installer` for the full functionality. Often

```
sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /
```

is all that's needed. The target is a "device" (see the man page for details or run `installer -dominfo`). Here `/` is the main drive, it also accepts devices like `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`, or `/dev/disk0`.

Comment: This was a workaround for installing a `.pkg` file that failed GUI installation with a useless ["The installer encountered an error"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275915/debugging-the-installer-encountered-an-error-that-caused-the-installation-to-fa) message.

Answer (score 25):

Just in case it's needed; if you want to installer a .pkg without root access:

```
installer -pkg myapp.pkg -target CurrentUserHomeDirectory
```

will install the package in ~/Applications.

Comment: Is `CurrentUserHomeDirectory` in this case a special literal token? Or is that to be replaced with `$HOME`?

Comment: @coolaj86 It's a literal token

Answer (score 8):

Install all `.pkg` files from the current folder to `/Applications` (or whatever target folder is configured in the package):

```bash
for f in *.pkg; do
    sudo installer -verbose -pkg "$f" -target /
done
```

As an alternative you can install the packages to your home folder with `-target ~`. They will end up in `/Users/<your_account>/Applications` unless a specific path is predefined in the installer.

> <sup>If you want to see which specific folders a pkg installer writes to and which post-install scripts will be run then check out [SuspiciousPackage](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/get.html) (freeware, can be installed with `brew install --cask suspicious-package`), and use quick preview from Finder when a `.pkg` file is selected. Pressing spacebar in Finder with the selected file should work too. A similar shareware (nagware) app — [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/), can be used for inspecting and unpacking dmg/pkg and other container formats.</sup>

###### Handling files with spaces and special characters

While the `for f in *.xyz` syntax looks 'clean' and neat, it is considered bad practice in bash because it is likely to fail on file names with spaces, quotes and other special chars. A more foolproof approach is to use `find`, e.g.

```bash
sudo -i

find . -iname "*.pkg" -maxdepth 1 -exec installer -verbose -pkg {} -target / \;
```

<sup>Note:`-maxdepth 1` forces `find` to only search for files in the current folder and avoid traversing the nested subfolders.</sup>

Comment: This doesn't necessarily install to `/Applications` - it depends on the package, for example PowerShell for macOS installs to `/usr/local`.

Comment: I've put this in an answer as well, but `-target CurrentUserHomeDirectory` is what I've used successfully for Microsoft Edge and Logitech Camera Settings app.