# Debugging "The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail."?

Tags: install, error, pkg

While trying to install a PKG installer package, I've run into an issue where it refuses to finish installing.

The PKG almost finishes, but ends with the following error, and does not finish installing.

> The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

The macOS version is the latest and a fresh install, and it is the latest version of the software, but I'm not particularly interested in my specific case, as I already chanced upon a workaround. I'm mostly interested in debugging why it fails to install.

Is there any way to debug a failed Installer package to find out anything about why it failed?

I tried checking Console, but didn't find anything. I also tried running `Installer.app` by the command line in the hopes it would give me something to go on.

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
```

Unfortunately, it just repeated the message in Terminal.

```
2017-03-10 14:02:45.426 Installer[654:7354] The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

I was hoping to be able to find out *something* more about *why* it is failing. Just telling a manufacture, "it just doesn't finish installing on my machine" really doesn't seem very productive if there is no way to figure out *why*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha! It turns out the log for the installer can be found in the application menu.

<kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Installer Log</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)

[image: Window -> Installer Log]

You may need to set the log window to <kbd>Show All Logs</kbd> to see all the relevant information:

[image: Show All Logs]

Comment: I see "archive open fail" in the log. Now what?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I haven't seen that one before, but my guess would be it means the pkg files is damaged, incomplete, or maybe not-signed. Maybe try clearing the quarantine xattr's for the file if you think the issue might be the latter.

Comment: The package was fine per `pkgutil --pkg-info`. I installed with `sudo installer -pkg MacPorts-2.8.1-13-Ventura.pkg -target /`. ‍♂️

Comment: I'm new to MacOS and was doing this from Recovery Mode, so the above option wasn't available to me. However, I was able to find it in /var/log/install.log.