# pkg installer installs to inconsistent locations

Tags: terminal, install

When I install my Xamarin-generated package with the terminal command from [Installing .pkg with terminal ?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal)

```
sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /
```

the place it actually gets installed is inconsistent, even from the same package.

Sometimes it goes to Applications. Sometimes it goes to

```
myProject/bin/debug
```

Sometimes it goes to

```
myProject/bin/Distribution/
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Installer -target doesn't take an absolute path as an argument it takes a volume.

The installation path is determined when you build the package. Not via the -target flag