# How Do I Upgrade VirtualBox from the Command Line

Tags: macos, terminal, virtualbox

I need to remotely log into a Mac to upgrade VirtualBox.  The problem is screen sharing is just abysmally slow and I don't want to use 3rd party screen sharing utilities.  I prefer to do this in Terminal (SSH) as it's much more efficient for me.

**Is there a way to upgrade VirtualBox from the command line?**

Answer (score 11):

### How to upgrade VirtualBox via the Command Line in macOS - 5 steps!

This is a quick guide on how to upgrade (install) VirtualBox from the command line.   It will involve mounting a .dmg, installing a .pkg, and finally upgrading (installing) the Extension Pack.

#### Prerequisites

This guide assumes you have already downloaded the required files found on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and have `sudo` privileges.

You also need the names or UUIDS of the running VMs. You can get that by using the `VBoxManage list runningvms` command.  Remember if you use the VM name and it has spaces, you must encapsulate it in quotes.  Example: `VBoxManage showvminfo "My VM"`

#### 1.  ***Shutdown all running VMs and VirtualBox Application***

Shutting down VMs is as simple as logging in and powering down the VM.  However, since this is "Terminal only" solution, we need to look at the `savestate` function in `VBoxManage`.

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vmname|UUID> savestate
```

Issue that command for each VM by name or UUID and it will automatically save the "position" of the running VM and then close it.  This is equivalent to selecting the **Close** item in **Machine Menu** of the VirtualBox GUI.

Note:  This is not like "pulling the plug"  This will save the machine state so that when you power back on, it will pick up right where it left off.

Next, we need to make sure the VirtualBox GUI (management console) isn't running.  To kill the VirtualBox GUI, just issue the command:

```
killall VirtualBox
```

#### 2.  ***Mount the VirtualBox Installation .dmg***<sup>1</sup>

```
hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/VirtualBox-Version.dmg
```

You will see several "Checksumming" messages and when finished, you will see the `disks` and mount point that the image was attached to similar to below (these device identifiers and names will differ from yours):

```
/dev/disk5              GUID_partition_scheme
/dev/disk5s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/VirtualBox
```

The important piece is `/Volumes/VirtualBox`.  This is where the installer will be located.

#### 3. ***Install the .pkg***<sup>2</sup>

Next, we're going to run the installer to install the .pkg file. Located on the volume we just mounted.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg -target /
```

If you get the following message, go back to step 1

```
installer: Error - The installer has detected running virtual machines. Please shut down all running VirtualBox machines and then restart the installation
```

If all goes well, you should see the following message:

```
installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
```

You can verify that the new version was installed by issuing the command:

```
VBoxManage --version
```

#### 4. ***Install the Extension Pack***

To upgrade the Extension Pack, you need to remove the old one and install the new one.  You can use the `VirtualBoxManage extpack uninstall [--force] { name }` and `VBoxManage extpack install {tarball}` commands, but luckily, Oracle provided us with a `--replace` option to do it in one step:

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace ~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-version.vbox-extpack
```

There will be some license terms, simply enter "Y" to accept.  If successful, you will see the following message:

```
Successfully installed "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
```

#### 5. ***Restart your VMs and Eject Your Volume***

Success!  You're all done.  Restart your VMs as needed

```
VBoxManage startvm <vmname|UUID> [--type headless|GUI|seperate]
```

Most of my VMs are headless boxes so I issue the command with the `--type headless` option

```
VBoxManage startvm "FreeBSD" --type headless
```

Don't forget to eject the installation media volume.  You won't want unsuspecting users coming in and finding attached volumes!

```
hdiutil eject /Volumes/VirtualBox
```

---

#### References and further reading

<sup>1</sup>[Is there a command to install a dmg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg)

<sup>2</sup>[Installing .pkg with terminal ?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal)

[VBManage Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/E97727/html/vboxmanage-intro.html)

Comment: Wow! Regarding step 1: Is there a way to query all running VirtualBox VMs via `VBoxManage`? Might be difficult otherwise to know which VMs to shutdown (and restart in step 5).

Comment: @nohillside - The command is `VBoxManage list runningvms`.  I’ll work it into the answer, somehow.

Comment: Have you [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed? You could simply issue `brew cask upgrade virtualbox`. (Maybe you’d have to stop your VM’s first manually, I haven’t tested it.)

Comment: @Melebius -  I don’t use Homebrew.

Comment: One-liner for the boring step 1.1: `VBoxManage list runningvms | sed -E 's/.*\{(.*)\}/\1/' | xargs -L1 -I {} VBoxManage controlvm {} savestate`(tested in 10.11 - worrrrks).

Comment: @klanomath - That's awesome!  I think this calls for another Q/A post with some useful VBox functions that this question can link to.  I have a few of my own.. like one that extracts the UUID, an alias for VBoxManage, etc.  That one you just posted is golden.

Comment: @Allan Golden would be: save all "savestate" VM UUIDs, which have been running before updating VBox, to some temp file and automatically start them again 1by1 after updating VBox with the help of this temp file...

Comment: This is amazing!